# What is the Atlas's head?

Tags: mechwarrior-online

I keep hearing that the Atlas's head's hitbox is actually the left eye. Whose left is that though? Is it the attacker's left or the Atlas's left?

Comment: Typically, mech component locations are given from the Mech's perspective, so I'd assume it's the Atlas's left eye, but I haven't verified that. Related note: The damage display for your currently targeted enemy has right and left flipped for convenience.

Comment: I got rather close to an Atlas's head today and noticed that the left eye (i.e. the one on the right for somebody looking at it head-on) had some extra graphical detail - fairly sure that's it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While playing yesterday I noticed that the Atlas cockpit's window isn't symmetrical:
[image: Inside of the Atlas's cockpit with the right side higher up]
As you can see, the right side is higher than the left.

This parallels looking at an Atlas from the outside:
[image: An Atlas from the outside, with the eyes both being higher in the middle]
As you can see, the eyes are both higher in the middle, so apparently the cockpit's in the Atlas's left eye, or the right from an onlooker's perspective, like the commenters said.